# Android support for SHA-1 certificates

Tags: android, sha1

SHA-1 is known as weak now and many browsers are going to mark it as insecure. So I'm wondering if it would also be deprecated on Android system in the near future?

The backend of my APP is using a SHA-1 certificate for HTTPS, and I've read that [Chrome would stop supporting it since 2017](https://security.googleblog.com/2015/12/an-update-on-sha-1-certificates-in.html). Is there any similar plan for Android?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven’t yet found a convenient, authoritative online source for each Android version’s root certificates. If you have a known stock Nexus device or the Android code base of interest, you can extract the platform certificates from there. Keep in mind that OEMs and carriers have a little flexibility in adding/removing root certificates in Android and AT&T proactively tracks deprecations and new root certificate introductions by major CAs.

Unfortunately, unlike with the deprecation of MD5, where SHA-1 was widely available across even legacy browsers, SHA-2 support is more limited. Windows XP older than Service Pack 3, for instance, has no SHA-2 support. In addition, **many less than 5-year-old Android phones (pre-Gingerbread) don't support SHA-2 completely**. Given how difficult some carriers make it to upgrade phones, many of these legacy phones are still in use today.

[Link](https://blog.cloudflare.com/sha-1-deprecation-no-browser-left-behind/)

Answer (score 0):

As per google policy there are no plan in near future to avoid SHA-1.